# Given a vector space $V$, show that the following statements are equivalent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a subset $W$ of $V$ then I want show that,

$\forall v \in V, w \in W$ $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $w + \alpha v \in W$ for any $0 < \alpha < \lambda$

iff

$\forall v \in V, w \in W$ $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda w + (1-\lambda) \alpha v \in W$ for any $0 < \lambda < 1 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first suppose $\forall w \in W ,v\in V\ \exists \lambda $ such that $w+\alpha v \in W\ \forall  0<\alpha<\lambda$ consider $\lambda <1$ so :

$w+\alpha (1-\lambda )(\frac{-w}{\alpha}+v)\in W $ so $w-w+\lambda w+\alpha(1-\lambda )v \in V$ $\to$ $\lambda w +\alpha (1-\lambda)v \in V$

on the other hand :

if $\forall w \in W , v\in V\ \exists \alpha $ such that $\lambda w+(1-\lambda )\alpha v \in V$ $\forall 0<\lambda<1$

consider $\lambda =\epsilon $ so $\epsilon w +(1- \epsilon )\alpha (\frac{w}{\alpha}+\frac{v}{1-\epsilon})\in W$ so $w+\alpha v \in W$

Comment: Nice, very nice work, Somaye. Did you contact to Will? Has the problem solved? :)

Comment: Thanks Babak .Yes i sent him my thesis

Comment: hi here weather is hot and work is too busy what about you?

Comment: Hanuz garma naymade. :-O